# Different linebreaks for chapter title on the chapter title page and in the Notes subheading (memoir)

Tags: memoir, patching

I would like to specify my own line breaks for a chapter title in three places:

1. on the chapter title page (ie first page of the chapter),
2. in the corresponding subheading in the Notes chapter (ie for `\pagenote`), and
3. in the ToC.

I can write `\chapter[A display\\of hot dogs: Oscar Meyer, Inc.]{A display\\of\\hot dogs:\\Oscar Meyer, Inc.}`, but in the Notes chapter, the subheading will default to the ToC entry. In `memoir`, I can redefine `\pnchap` to set the chapter subheading for Notes, but how should I redefine it? The `memoir` manual offers no examples. An attempt and an MWE below -- I'm out of my element.

## Desired output

[image: desired outupt]

## Attempt

I thought of redifining the `\chapter` command to have a third argument like,

```latex
\chapter%
[A display\\of hot dogs: Oscar Meyer, Inc.]%
{A display\\of\\hot dogs:\\Oscar Meyer, Inc.}%
{A display of hot dogs:\\Oscar Meyer, Inc.}
```

where the new third argument would ultimately get printed as the chapter subheading in Notes. To implement that, I tried:

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@m@mchapter}[1][]{%
  \def\ch@pt@c{#1}%
  \@ifnextchar[{\my@chapter}{\my@chapter[]}%
}
\def\my@chapter[#1]#2#3{\def\f@rxtra{#3}\@chapter[#1]#2}
\renewcommand{\pnchap}{\f@rxtra}
\makeatother
```

But I got this error:

```
! Parameters must be numbered consecutively.
<to be read again>
                   ##
l.38 \end
         {document}
```

which I don't really understand. I guess there's some issue with the `\my@chapter` definition.

## MWE

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% % ATTEMPT 1
% \makeatletter
% \renewcommand{\@m@mchapter}[1][]{%
%   \def\ch@pt@c{#1}%
%   \@ifnextchar[{\my@chapter}{\my@chapter[]}%
% }
% \def\my@chapter[#1]#2#3{\def\f@rxtra{#3}\@chapter[#1]#2}
% \renewcommand{\pnchap}{\f@rxtra}
% \makeatother

\makepagenote

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Foo}

% % ATTEMPT 1
% \chapter%
% [A display\\of hot dogs: Oscar Meyer, Inc.]%
% {A display\\of\\hot dogs:\\Oscar Meyer, Inc.}%
% {A display of hot dogs:\\Oscar Meyer, Inc.}

\lipsum[1]\pagenote{Blah blah}
\printpagenotes
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a little bit easier without trying to overwrite existing `\chapter`:

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mychapter[3][]{\def\f@rxtra{#3}\chapter[#1]{#2}}
\renewcommand{\pnchap}{\f@rxtra}
\makeatother
```

and then

```latex
\mychapter[some line\\breaks]{some\\line\\breaks}{some\\line breaks}
```